# How to customize wordpress visual editor HTML output

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm creating a custom theme for a portfolio site. This is my first custom theme in wordpress. So far i've managed to solve most of my issues googling around but this one (although I find it unlikely that nobody ever needed this) I was not able to find.

The problem: I need to customize the HTML tags and CSS classes that visual editor outputs. To better explain I'll post pictures and code:

This is the content in the visual editor:
[image]

This is the default wordpress HTML output for that:

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis 
    ornare 
    lectus nec sapien venenatis iaculis. Praesent consequat at neque 
    a 
    placerat. Nunc vel lacus lectus. Aliquam non tempus mauris.

    &nbsp;

    <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-14" 
    src="http://192.168.25.187/wordpress/wp-
    content/uploads/2017/07/Magazine-1.jpg" alt="" width="474" 
    height="315" />
```

This is my desired markup:

```
    <h5>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis 
    ornare 
    lectus nec sapien venenatis iaculis. Praesent consequat at neque 
    a 
    placerat. Nunc vel lacus lectus. Aliquam non tempus mauris.</h5>

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-8">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="galeria1" 
       ref="http://192.168.25.187/wordpress/wp-
       content/uploads/2017/07/Magazine-1.jpg" title="teste">
        <img class="img-responsive"     
          src="http://192.168.25.187/wordpress/wp-
          content/uploads/2017/07/Magazine-1.jpg" alt="" width="474" 
          height="315" /></a>
     </div>
    </div>
```

What files do I need to edit (or functions to write) to modify the default visual editor HTML and CSS output?

Comment: This is a bit tricky but i have already done this twice. You will have to use the_content filter. And then find all images and replace them with your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work using PHP native `DOMDocument` function. Here's how it works:

First, we need to print the text content of `the_content()`. Since I dont want images, we'll strip all tags:

```
<h5><?php echo wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_content()); ?></h5>
```

This obviously comes with the downside that it strips *all* tags, `<strong>` and `<a>` included. Will come back to solve this when I find how.

Now, to display the images within the code I want, we need to parse `the_content()` and find all `<img>` tags with `DOMDocument`:

```
<?php
  $content = get_the_content();
  $dom = new DOMDocument;
    if ($dom->loadHTML($content)) {
    $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
      if ($imgs->length > 0) {
        foreach ($imgs as $img) {
         $img->getAttribute('src');
        }
      }
    }
?>
```

This last line `$img->getAttribute('src');` will store all images url's into the $img array. Finally, we just need to print the contents of the array inside a loop for each image in the post:

```
<?php foreach ($imgs as $img) { ?>
                    <a class="fancybox" rel="galeria1" href="<?php echo $img->getAttribute('src'); ?>" title="<?php echo $img->getAttribute('alt'); ?>">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $img->getAttribute('src'); ?>" alt="<?php echo $img->getAttribute('alt'); ?>" width="<?php echo $img->getAttribute('width'); ?>" height="<?php echo $img->getAttribute('height'); ?>"></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Note that with `getAttribute();` I can retrieve every attribute I need from the parsed tag, including title, alt text and width/height provided by the user in the backend.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2:**

You could try to use shortcodes. You would put something like this in functions.php.

```
function myh5content_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
  return __("<h5><span>$content</h5>");
}
add_shortcode('h5content', 'myh5content_shortcode');

function myimg_shortcode( $atts, $content ) {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-8">
      <a class="fancybox" rel="galeria1" 
       ref="http://192.168.25.187/wordpress/wp-
       content/uploads/2017/07/Magazine-1.jpg" title="teste">
        <?php echo $content ?>
        </a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();  
}
add_shortcode( 'imgcontent', 'myimg_shortcode' );
```

And then use those shortcodes in posts like this:

```
[h5content]Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis 
    ornare 
    lectus nec sapien venenatis iaculis. Praesent consequat at neque 
    a 
    placerat. Nunc vel lacus lectus. Aliquam non tempus mauris.

    &nbsp;[/h5content]

[imgcontent]<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-14" 
    src="http://192.168.25.187/wordpress/wp-
    content/uploads/2017/07/Magazine-1.jpg" alt="" width="474" 
    height="315" />[/imgcontent]
```

I would put the anchor tag inside the post too, so that only the `<div>` with classes are used in the shortcode. That way, the shortcode could be reused for other posts. Hopefully, the code above can guide you towards the solution.

Comment: Thank you! I may be doing something wrong, but this is putting everything in the post (images included) inside a <h5> tag, and <img> tags inside <p> tags. Also, I customized your code to dinamically get images URL through get_posts() function, once all is working I'll add an answer to add completeness.

Comment: Are the images in the content?

Comment: yes I inserted them from within the visual editor as  the picture shows

Comment: Then I misunderstood the question. Let me try something.

Comment: Updated the answer again.

Comment: Thanks but I've got it to work with html tags parsing since I did not want the user to type shortcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Following your file path to the folder the permalink states and edit that directly. It is a test file correct?

```
index.php/2017/07/28/test
```

You may want to locate the img easily using chrome's right-click inspect.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create some sort of HTML template with placeholders so you only have to enter the placeholders (text and image url) and your template takes care of the rest.

You could use a free plugin like [Snippy](https://wordpress.org/plugins/snippy/) to do this. Full disclosure, I'm the author of the plugin.

Snippy lets you can create your own shortcodes and pick names for them. Then you can add pieces of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to the shortcode (in Snippy these are named "bits"). You then place the shortcode on a page or post, and Snippy will output your HTML instead.

So for your situation you could create an HTML bit based your HTML snippet and add a `{{text}}` and `{{image}}` placeholder to it:

```
<h5>{{text}}</h5>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <a class="fancybox" rel="galeria1" ref="{{image}}" title="tests">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="{{image}}" alt="" width="474" height="315" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can then add this HTML bit to a custom shortcode and use the shortcode in your text editor. Now you can re-use the above HTML snippet on your site without having to duplicate it everywhere.